How to Style a Text Input Field Without Affecting Other Text Input Fields?
How do I style an HTML text field without affecting the other text fields in my code? I have my text fields in a Class named "Command", which I have attempted to style with CSS. However, this styling is applied to all text fields across the application and not those within the "Command" Class.
I have tried the following:

Changing the order to specify the input type and the Command Class.

Removing the comma between the Command Class and input specification.


The first solution attempt did not change the result. The styling was consequently applied to all text fields.
The second solution did not change anything, and my styling for the other text fields was applied to the Command Class.
input[type = "text"], .Command {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: larger;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

<div class="memoryCommands">
                <input type="text" class="Command" placeholder="Enter Command 1">
                <input type="text" class="Command" placeholder="Enter Command 2">
                <input type="text" class="Command" placeholder="Enter Command 3">
            </div>


Spend a little time learning how CSS classes and IDs work. Your selector is close, but wrong. input[type = "text"], .Command should be input[type = "text"].Command, possibly just input.Command

@j08691 Kindly answered my question. The answer is:


input[type = "text"].Command 



